# Share link to pdf file in overleaf

Tags: overleaf

In overleaf it is possible to share the project you are working on with other to collaborate or just view. However, I was wondering if it is also possible to share a link which always gives the most up date versions compiled pdf file directly? I.e. I click the link and get to download a pdf file.

Comment: Doesn't Overleaf already provide this functionality with an extra click? That is, a link provides you a read-only view in Overleaf, which includes the PDF, that you can then download? Or do you want the link to automatically download the PDF?

Comment: Also, how about just using the download PDF URL for sharing?

Comment: This question is a bit off-topic for here, but we're always happy to answer questions about Overleaf features at Overleaf support: https://www.overleaf.com/contact (I'm on the support team). Currently no, there is not a PDF-only sharing option although it's something that's being considered for the future. If you have other questions, pls feel free to get in touch directly.

Comment: Thank you both. I agree that this is a bit off topic, hope this will get implemented soon as feature.

Comment: @DanMacKinnon [How can one download several PDFs from Overleaf at once?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/168488/18147) (one PDF per project, the PDF corresponds to the compiled version of the project). Thanks!

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - the best way to ask Overleaf support questions is to send an email to support@overleaf.com or use the contact link: https://www.overleaf.com/contact. We're happy to answer questions like this, these questions seem off-topic here.

Comment: @DanMacKinnon thanks, it's on-topic on Webapps SE and a better use of human time to make your great answer publicly available.